# what is the probability that every man marry this year??

Tags: probability

In the Goland Kingdom, there are always more unmarried women, 18 years old or more,
than unmarried men, 18 years old or more. Because of this, the king gave the following law.
On the 1st of April of every year, each unmarried women 18 years old or more has to tell
the king on a written note her name and the name of one unmarried man older 18 years or
more that she proposes to marry. The king collects all the notes and give to each man the
note addressed to him. Each man can get no proposal, one proposal, or several proposals. If
a man gets no proposal, he will remain unmarried until the next year. If a man gets exactly
one propoasal, he has to accept it and marry. If a man gets more than one proposal, he
must choose his bride from the list of all unmarried women that proposed him and marry. If
this year there are m unmarried women and n unmarried men, what is the probability that
every man marry this year?

Comment: By using the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion.)

Comment: Are you assuming that every woman picks randomly among all men a uniform distribution? That seems not very realistic.

Comment: Unless you know how many marriable women are there, there is no way to compute anything.

Answer (score 1):

The women's option will determine a function from $W$ to $M$ where $W$ is the set of available women and $M$ the set of available men (available sounds better than unmarried).

All men will marry if the function is surjective. so the probability is just the number of surjective functions from $W$ to $M$ divided by the number of functions from $W$ to $M$.

The hard part is finding how many surjective functions there are from $W$ to $M$. In other words how many surjective functions exist from a set of caridinality $n$ to a set of cardinality $m$.

So first you need to find out in how many ways you can  partitions a set of size $n$ into $m$ parts. This is done via stirling numbers of the second class.

Then select which element of range is mapped by each of the parts in $m!$ ways.

Therefore the probability is $$\frac{|M|!S(|W|,|M|)}{|W|^{|M|}}\cdot$$

Comment: you might also want to read up on the twelvefold way

Comment: Can you please explain how you use stirling numbers in order to partition a set of size n into m parts? @User4140

Comment: an can you please explain the last part of the solution more explicitly? @user4140

Comment: The number of ways to partition a set of size n into m parts is exactly S(n,m). Once a partition has been chosen(so the bundles of the domain have been asserted). All that is left to chose is which of these bundles will map to each of the elements of the codomain. We can do this in m! ways. So there are n!(S(n,m) surjective functions. However the probability a function will be surjective is (number of surjective functions)/(number of functions) and the number of functions is $n^m$